Don't bind PDOStatement 'NOW()' as timestamp
I've faked the NOW() function in my postgresql database so it returns a set date using this answer that modifies the user's search path. I'm using a MVC library and can see the queries it's sending with ALTER DATABASE db SET log_statement = 'all';, I was able to recreate the behavior with a basic PDO:
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);


When I run a query without bound variables it sends the expected query to the database and stores the faked date in the table:

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES (NOW());")->execute();
// LOG: execute pdo_stmt: INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES (NOW());


When I try to bind the value with either bindParam or bindValue it sends a timestamp as the bound value:

$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES (:now);");
$now = 'NOW()';
$sql->bindValue(':now', $now);
$sql->execute();

// LOG: execute pdo_stmt: INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES ($1);
// DETAIL:  Parameters: $1 = '2024-10-15 16:43:27.437313+00'


With feedback from aynber I was able to recreate the behavior with a string, which makes me think this could be an SQL thing:

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES ('NOW())';")->execute();
// LOG: execute pdo_stmt: INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES ('NOW()');
// Table stores '2024-10-15 17:47:44.796556+00' 

The MVC library is binding values before trying to write to the database, which skips my faked function. I've tried disabling the emulate prepares setting with $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); but that make any difference since it's only available for the OCI, Firebird, and MySQL drivers according to the docs.
My question: Is there any way to bind the NOW() function in a statement so that it runs like case #1, instead of the other cases where it is binding the current timestamp or a string (that evaluates to the current timestamp)?

I don't think it works that way. Query binding treats the bound value as a string or integer. This means your query, if written out, would look like INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES ("NOW()"), where NOW() is a string value. It would not be treated as the function. Since it's an invalid value for the field, the database is either possibly using a default value, or assuming some sort of value.

@aynber Aha, you're right! I'll update my question, might not be a workaround then

@aynber it turns out, now is not invalid but one of special values and braces are also allowed somehow.

@YourCommonSense Are they allowed when parameter binding? NOW() isn't valid for postgresql, but from the links the OP provided, it sounds like they created an sql function to mimic it.

@aynber I don't know about function (though evidently it's supported), but I am talking of string value.

@aynber, now() is a builtin function in PostgreSQL. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT
